# Python 3.5.2 can be accessed through Terminal, but IDLE for 3.5.2 is missing

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, pyqt4, python-3.5

I am just getting started with Python and computer programming in general, so hopefully someone can help me out. I am trying to use PyQt4 to start learning how to code GUI's, and eventually use py2app to bundle these GUI's into Mac Applications...

The issue I am having is I just installed PyQt4 (or so I thought) on my computer, using MacPorts (http://www.pythonschool.net/pyqt/distributing-your-application-on-mac-os-x/). When following the guide, I did slightly modify the code I entered into terminal. At first, when I  typed the `sudo port install py33-pyqt4` command into Terminal, it returned

```
Error: Port py33-pyqt4 not found
```

So, I changed the command to `sudo port install py35-pyqt4`, which successfully installed python 3.5.2 along with PyQt4. When I type `python3.5` into Terminal, Python3.5.2 loads, with PyQt4 working as well. I am able to import modules from PyQt4. Not sure if changing the command to install python 3.5.2 is what cause my issue.

The issue is this: I am unsure how to use IDLE (or another IDE, PyCharm for example) with python 3.5.2! I cannot find an IDLE version for python 3.5.2 on my computer. I do have python 3.5.1 and python 2.7 installed, along with their respective IDLE programs. PyQt4 modules, however, cannot be imported when I use these IDLE versions.

When I issued the `sudo port install py35-pyqt4` command, did it install IDLE somewhere? Am I able to use PyCharm with python 3.5.2, if python 3.5.2 loads properly into Terminal? I just need some way to edit scripts outside of Terminal. Hopefully this is a clear enough question!

UPDATE:

I found the IDLE program... Realized that it was installed through MacPorts it is located in a MacPorts folder in my Applications folder. The only issue it that it will not open. Frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

I also have IDLE programs which won't start. Not sure why.

If you are willing to use PyCharm, I would recommend that to you anyway. You can change the pythonpath in the PyCharm Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Console -> Python Console -> Python interpreter. Select here the appropriate Python binary.

If you are unsure about the pythonpath, type

```
which python3.5
```

in a terminal which should give you the path.

With that, PyCharm uses this Python version as your default.